# OWL API: How to assign domain to range on OWLObjectProperty

Tags: java, netbeans, owl-api

In fact I want to create an ontology based in a list of concepts(String) and relationships between concepts(Map). I have two types of relation "kind of" and “sub Topic of". So I tried to create this ontology trough owl api. To create relation between two OWL classes I used OWLObjectPreportyDomain and OWLObjectProprertyRange and specified a relation through OWLObjectProperty. 
My problem is when I create a relation that has many domains and many ranges, I didn't find a manner to assign each domain to each range. 
I want to find a solution for that. Could any one give me an idea ?

For example I have this Map : `Map<String, String> relation = new HashMap<String, String>;` which contains two concepts and relation between each other.
`LinkedList<Map<String, String>> listRelation = new LikedList<Map<String,String>>;`
this list contains the list of relation between concepts.
`relation("concept1")="AUTHETICATION";`
`realtion("relation")="kind of";`
`relation("concept2")="VALIDATION";`
`listRelation.add(relation);`
`relation = new HashMap<String, String>;`
`relation("concept1")="ENCRYPTION";`
`realtion("relation")="kind of";`
`relation("concept2")="CRYPTHOGRAPHY";`
`listRelation.add(relation);`
And I create an other Map which contains concept and his instance like: 
`Map<String,String> inst;`
`inst("concept")="authentication";` 
`inst("instance")="topNet";`
how could I create this in OWL. Concepts are OWLClass or OWLNamedIndividual. If they are OWLNamedIndividual so instances are what. Moreover if concepts are OWLClass how to declare relation between them ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'each domain to each range'? There is no particular relation between a domain class expression and a range class expression, in OWL

Comment: I will intorduce in the following an example:
 
"AUTHENTIFICATION"  concept is a kind of "VALIDATION" concept and "ENCRYPTION" is kind of "CRYPTOGRAPHY".
 
In this case, I have two domains AUTHENTIFICATION and ENCRYPTION" and two ranges VALIDATION and CRYPTOGRAPHY.
 
Therefore, The OWLObjectProperty:"#kind of" has  two domains and two ranges but when I check the .owl file I can't know which range is for which domains.

Comment: From your example I get the impression that `Authentication` and `Validation` are not classes but individuals, and that what you have are assertions and not domain and range declarations. However, declaring multiple domains is equivalent to declaring an intersection of all classes listed and assigning it to be the domain; same for the range. There isn't a preferred domain for a particular range. What you can do is, e.g., writing a class which is a subclass of the domain and of `all kind_of range

Answer (score 0):

From your example I get the impression that `Authentication` and `Validation` are not classes but individuals, and that what you have are assertions and not domain and range declarations.

However, declaring multiple domains is equivalent to declaring an intersection of all classes listed and assigning it to be the domain; same for the range. There isn't a preferred domain for a particular range.

What you can do is, e.g., writing a class C subclass of Authentication and subclass of `all kind_of Validation`, which, for any instance, will assert domain and range equivalent for `kind_of`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But I'm still bit confused how to distinguish between OWLClass and OWLIndividual. In fact my ontology has concepts and instances. To implement it in OWL language I thought that concept is a class and instance is an individual. on my exemple Authentication  and Validation are declared as concepts in the ontology. I could use `OWLNamedIndividual` to declare concept in OWL ?

Comment: It's becoming difficult to discuss this without a concrete example. Can you add your ontology, or the relevant portion, to the question?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question and I added a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

class = concept, 
individual = instance (of a class, you instantiate a class to get an individual)

I'll continue with the assumption that you consider these classes/concepts.

If you just want to say that Encryption is a type of Cryptography, then you only need to declare Ecryption subClassOf Cryptography. No need of object properties at all.

If you have other types of relations that you want to use, say "hasRelationYTo" you'll write the axiom, something like

> Encryption and hasRelationYTo some/only Cryptography (Manchester syntax)

Like Ignazio said,

> There is no particular relation between a domain class expression and
>   a range class expression, in OWL

The range and domain of the property (=relation=function) are generic and meant to prevent errors. This means you cannot specify

Domain1 - propA - Range1 (but not, say Domain2 - propA - Range1)

Domain2- propA -Range2

Object property declaration allows you *only* declarations like {Domain1 U Domain2} - propA - {Range1 U Range2} . If you really really need to do something like above, you'll have to use 2 different object properties propA and propB. This is often not the case and having multiple Domains and Ranges together is enough.

Here is the OWL file that models

"AUTHENTIFICATION" is a kind of "VALIDATION"

"ENCRYPTION" is kind of "CRYPTOGRAPHY"

Also, you might want to have a look at the protege pizza tutorial to get a better feeling of OWL . If I remember well, it only takes about 20 mins to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
```

]>

```
<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#is_a_kind_of -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#is_a_kind_of"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#AUTHENTIFICATION -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#AUTHENTIFICATION">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#is_a_kind_of"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Validation"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Cryptography -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Cryptography">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#is_a_kind_of"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Encryption"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Encryption -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Encryption"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Validation -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/tudose/ontologies/2014/3/untitled-ontology-59#Validation"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. In fact I try to create a new ObjectProperty with the same URI as I have many concepts that are linked with the same type of relationship but it refers to a single ObjectProperty automatically.  therefore as a conclusion we  can not have multiple ObjectProperty with the same IRI. I thought about using SubClassOf  but I have other types of relationships. I really have not succeeded in finding a solution that doing about this problem

Comment: No, you cannot use the same URI for different objects, U stands for unique.

Comment: I think maybe you are trying to model your example at the property level instead of adding an axiom?

Comment: thank you for your help. My problem is besides of relation KindOf I have other relations like subTopicOf, parTOf... and it has multiple domain and range.
Im adding an axiom:`genders.add(factory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(sub-topicOf, c1,c2));` which `genders` is a `HashSet<OWLAxiom>()` and then I do this ` List<OWLOntologyChange> la=manager.addAxioms(ontology, genders); manager.applyChanges(la)`
I just need to declare c1 and c2 as OWLClass not an OWLNamedIndividual as in this example in the given code. I read OWL documentation and I can't found solution.I hope that I will find it here.

Comment: An other question please : could we make relation between two OWLClass trough AWLAnnotationAssertion and it has the same result as OWLObjectProperty ??
Thanks in advance for the answer.